# CORS OPTIONS Succeeds but GET /connect/userinfo is stalled

Tags: vue.js, nginx, kubernetes, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have a JavaScript client that uses the implict flow to log a user into an environment protected by Identity-Server 4. Identity-Server is running in a kubernetes container which is proxied by NGINX.  The JavaScript client is using Vue.js and Vuex-Oidc.

This setup works will in most environment. Unfortunately some of our clusters fail in a strange way

The GET connect/userinfo causes a preflight OPTIONS request. The OPTIONS Request succeeds with a 204. The GET is never issued by the browser and is noted as stalled in chromium-based browsers and blocked in Firefox.

Examination of the response headers from the OPTIONS request in working and non-working environments reveal no differences.

Note that from Identity-Server's perspective the CORS call on connect/userinfo was successful. It returned a 204. The headers say that the allowed origin is the URI of my browser application. They also say that an authentication header is allowed and a GET method is allowed.

I have run out of things to look for. Has anyone seen this sort of problem?

Comment: Nginx configuration ?

Comment: can u post ur client config on IdentityServer?

Comment: Any error in the browser console? also please post a sample copy of your Startup.Configure method.